# How to create an alias for a mercurial user?

Tags: mercurial, aliases

I am looking for a way to create an alias for a user that has commited to a mercurial repository. For example, if there is a user named user1 I'd like every commit done by him to be under the name user2.

Comment: Do you mean the `-u` option to `hg commit`?  Or are you looking for a way to change that username at the repository so that if I check in with a username of 'john.doe', Mercurial will change it to 'joe.soap'?

Comment: I know about the -u option. I need to do exactly what you described in the end!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about changing the name that was already used for some commits, you can do that using `hg convert` with a source and destination type of `hg` and a `--authors` mapping file.  However, in doing so you change the hash of every changeset, and if anyone has already cloned your repo you'll be hosing them.

If you're talking about commits to come, then just make them whatever you want using the `-u` option to `hg commit`.